# Same code compiles on Dev C++ but not on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

```
#include<cstdlib>           //Required for compatibility
#include<cmath>             //Required for pow
#include<fstream>           //Required for data files
#include<iostream>          //Required for cout and cin
#include<iomanip>           //Required for setw

using namespace std;

int choice, loops, count;
double initTime, timeIncrement, finalTime, time, A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, 
altitude, A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, velocity;         //This is line 20 as the error notes            
//Declare variables
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;


void menuFunction() {                                                                               
//Main menu function where user selects which option they would like to proceed with, not relevant to question
}

double altitudeFunction(double& altitude) {                                                                         
//Altitude calculation
     altitude = A1 * pow(time, 4.0) + B1 * pow(time, 3.0) + C1 * pow(time, 2.0) + D1 * time + E1; //This is line 36 as the error notes
}

double velocityFunction(double& velocity) {                                                                         
//Velocity calculation
     velocity = A2 * pow(time, 4.0) + B2 * pow(time, 3.0) + C2 * pow(time, 2.0) + D1 * time + E1; // This is line 41, as the error notes
}

void parameters() {                                                                     
//Function to enter time parameters to save space, not relevant to errors      
}

int main() {
    menuFunction();

    while (choice != 4) {
        switch (choice) {

        case 1: {
            parameters();
            if (finalTime < 5 || finalTime > 24) {                                  
 //Required invalid entry error message                                             
//Redisplay menu to allow user another try
            }
            else {
               //Open input file for option 1
               //Find variables in input file
               //close input file and open output file                                                      
              //Make output file look neat
            //Column headers for output file for readability
                loops = (int)((finalTime - initTime) / timeIncrement);
                for (count = 0; count <= loops; count++) {                                      //For loop for incremental calculations, this is line 86 as the error notes
                time = initTime + count * timeIncrement;                                                                
                 //Run both calculation functions
                 //Print results to output file during for loop
            }
            //close output file
            system("CLS");
            //Print message to screen saying data was recorded to output file
        }
        break;
    }

    case 2: {
        parameters();
            if (finalTime < 5 || finalTime > 24) {                                  
 //Required invalid entry error message                                             
//Redisplay menu to allow user another try
            }
            else {
               //Open input file for option 1
               //Find variables in input file
               //close input file and open output file                                                      
              //Make output file look neat
            //Column headers for output file for readability
                loops = (int)((finalTime - initTime) / timeIncrement);
                for (count = 0; count <= loops; count++) {                                      //For loop for incremental calculations, this is line 118 as the error notes
                time = initTime + count * timeIncrement;                                                                
                 //Run both calculation functions
                 //Print results to output file during for loop
            }
            //close output file
            system("CLS");
            //Print message to screen saying data was recorded to output file
        }
        break;
    }

    case 3: {
    parameters();
            if (finalTime < 5 || finalTime > 24) {                                  
 //Required invalid entry error message                                             
//Redisplay menu to allow user another try
            }
            else {
               //Open input file for option 1
               //Find variables in input file
               //close input file and open output file                                                      
              //Make output file look neat
            //Column headers for output file for readability
                loops = (int)((finalTime - initTime) / timeIncrement);
                for (count = 0; count <= loops; count++) {                                      //For loop for incremental calculations, this is line 150 as the error notes
                time = initTime + count * timeIncrement;                                                                
                 //Run both calculation functions
                 //Print results to output file during for loop
            }
            //close output file
            system("CLS");
            //Print message to screen saying data was recorded to output file
        }
        break;
    }

    default: {
        cout << "\tInvalid Entry!\n\n";                                     //Error message if user enters an invalid menu option
        menuFunction();
    }
    }
}

    if (choice == 4) {
       //end program
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In my first semester of C++ coding, I don't understand why but for some reason when I run this exact program, it compiles fine in Dev C++ but I get a host of errors in Visual Studio 2017. I tried to copy and paste the errors but it wasn't formatting correctly, so basically every instance of 'time' and 'count' is giving me an error saying "'time/count' is ambiguous" and the following less common errors:

> Error C2659   '=': function as left operand   86, 118, 150
>
> Error   C2365   'time': redefinition: previous definition was
>   'function'   20
>
> Error C2297   '*': illegal, right operand has type 'time_t (__cdecl
>   *)(time_t *const )'   36, 41
>
> Error C2665   'pow': none of the 6 overloads could convert all the
>   argument types    36, 41

The program is supposed to pull weather balloon data inputs from input files, do some math to get altitude and velocity values at certain times, and output those values to a new data file. It compiles, runs, and works perfectly on Dev C++ but will not compile on Visual Studio. I only ask because I submitted this for a course and was given a 0 since it does not compile on the professor's computer, but works fine on mine. Any ideas?

Edited to remove my name as well as non-relevant parts of the code. Everything that was replaced by comments in the code works fine, the parts of the code that contained errors were preserved.

Comment: VS will be telling you where time & count were (re)defined ... you should follow those error messages

Comment: This is what happens if you use this &%^*!@#() and unnecessary `using namespace std` statement..

Comment: Almost assuredly due to different header file contents on each system.  Not every compiler is the same or has the same resource in the same include file. VS can be especially unforgiving about some ambiguities in code compared to g++/MinGW. Drop `using namespace std` and explicitly specify the namespace of your functions, which will help some. Additionally, be sure to check your code in several different compilers, especially the one used by the grader.

Comment: Aside: global variables are bad ... hmmmkay

Comment: Please try to reduce the size of code before posting to SO.  First thing would have been to reduce the number of cases you were simulating; secondly remove all the output; thirdly remove the input (and hard code some numbers); fourthly reduce the complexity of some of the expressions.  I bet you could have easily got it down from 176 lines to 20 (at which point you might have seen what the problem was).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might show one reason why `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.

The standard library contains a [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function, which is brought in by the `using`.

Now the compiler doesn't know if plain `time` means the `::time` variable declared in this program or the `std::time` function.

The reason that it *might* compile on some systems is that a C++ standard header is allowed to indirectly include any other standard header. So it might happen that the standard library headers used with Dev-C++ by chance do not include `std::time`.